# OpenShift, Node.js and Forever

Tags: node.js, openshift

Good Day.

I would like to know if exist a way of using node.js forever module in OpenShift. I try to install it but due I don't have root permissions, I cannot make a global install, and using it locally doesn't work.

As additional information, I'm using a custom node.js cartridge, the one found here https://github.com/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift.

Thanks.

Comment: Does that custom cartridge not use node-supervisor like the official OpenShift Node.js cartridge? Or do you just want to switch node-supervisor with forever?

Comment: I'm aware supervisor would do the same as forever module, but I'm having difficulties using it so that's why I thought switching to Forever.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably have more success asking the author of the cartridge on GitHub for assistance. If node-supervisor isn't working in that cartridge you should file an issue report on GitHub.

Comment: The problem is supervisor works, but I need to execute a js file which uses a command line parameter as input, but fails to start properly. I'm trying to make work this project https://github.com/jsonchess/lightsquared.

Comment: I can see where that would be an issue. Is there any chance you could use environment variables instead of command line arguments in your application? That's the way settings like that are usually passed to applications on OpenShift.